# Xcode Bots not sending email on success/failure

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode5, xcode-bots

I setup Xcode Bots, which is working successfully. However, despite setting email addresses to get notified when a build is successful or it fails, I do not receive any emails. Is there any additional SMTP setup I need to do hidden somewhere?

Comment: Please take a look at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20436003/how-to-configure-email-settings-for-xcode-continuous-integration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to configure the Mac OSX Server for sending e-mail.

The local server is located in the Server application under "Mail" in the left sidebar.

I recently changed to using Amazon SES and had to edit the Postfix SASL configuration manually. Edit SASL password file, run `postmap`, enable SASL/TLS in `main.cf` configuration file and finally restart Postfix.

This detailed description by Rojas helped me:

http://benjaminrojas.net/configuring-postfix-to-send-mail-from-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/

Comment: Hi Niels, I've been trying setup the same configuration you have, and I've followed the description by Rojas but I've been unable to make it work with Amazon SES. I'd be really appreciate it if you could post everything you did to make it run properly with SES. Thanks

Comment: @NielsCastle I'm also having problems setting up Mac OS X Server to send emails through Amazon SES. Did you literally just follow Benjamin Rojas' guide? I have, but it's not working.

Comment: It could be outdated by now. I have moved on to Yosemite my self.

Answer (score 0):

I recently was tasked with doing the same thing, setting up OSX Server for sending e-mail.  What worked for me was setting up the postfix configuration manually as well but the link in the previous answer wasn't effective for me.  what was effective was following this tutorial

http://blog.anupamsg.me/2012/02/14/enabling-postfix-for-outbound-relay-via-gmail-on-os-x-lion-11/

and there's also a follow up that shows details to what needs to change to get it to work on Mavericks and newer http://blog.anupamsg.me/2013/12/22/enabling-postfix-on-osx-as-a-relay-revisited/