# Xcode Bots - Email via AWS SES

Tags: xcode, macos, email, amazon-web-services, osx-server

I'm trying to setup our Mac Mini running OS X Server to send emails when Xcode Bots fail.

I've so far followed these guides to the letter:

http://blog.anupamsg.me/2012/02/14/enabling-postfix-for-outbound-relay-via-gmail-on-os-x-lion-11/

http://benjaminrojas.net/configuring-postfix-to-send-mail-from-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/

http://www.anujgakhar.com/2011/12/09/using-macosx-lion-command-line-mail-with-gmail-as-smtp/

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183093/xcode-bots-not-sending-email-on-success-failure) StackOverflow question says that he was able to get AWS SES to work with Mac OS X Server, so it's possible.

Anyone done it and can give me any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I gave up and used [Mutt](http://www.mutt.org). Setting up Postfix is a bitch. Mutt is awesome! It works great for solving this issue.

You can install it via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) (\o/). [Here's](http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_using_mutt_email_client) a guide for setting it up and using it. You can simply invoke `mutt` from your Xcode Bot triggers.

To use with AWS SES just make SES SMTP credentials in the AWS console and enter these in to the `~/.muttrc` file.